# Why are there 5 subgroups that are generated by double transpositions on four elements in $S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

I am trying to calculate the total number of subgroups for each subgroup in $S_5$. I am working on subgroups of order $4$.

I understand that there are $\frac{{5 \choose 4}4!}{4}$ subgroups for $Z_4$ in $S_5$ (there are ${5 \choose 4}4!$ $4$-cycles in $S_5$ and 4 representations of the same subgroup). I also understand that there are $\frac{{5 \choose 2}{3 \choose 2}}{2}$ subgroups generated by a pair of disjoint transpositions (${5 \choose 2}$ selections for the first transposition, ${3 \choose 2}$ selections for the second transposition, and 2 representations of the same subgroup).

From my teacher, I know that I can create more Klein four-groups subgroups through two double transpositions. For example, $\{(), (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$ is a Klein four-group constructed through two double transpositions in $S_5$.

On further inspection from [this website](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S5#Subgroups), I know that there are $5$ subgroups generated by double transpositions on four elements in $S_5$.

Why are there 5 subgroups generated by double transpositions on four elements in $S_5$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** They're in bijection with the elements of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ they don't move.

Comment: May I ask what you mean by "they don't move"?

Comment: There exists an element $i$ of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that, for a given group $H$ of the type in question, @StackOverflow, we have $$\sigma(i)=i$$ for all $\sigma \in H$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding, but does that mean that there's a one to one correspondence between the number of Klein four-groups constructed through two double transpositions in $S_5$ and the element we don't include in the double transpositions?

Comment: Yes, @StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Shaun. How does removing one element from the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}  guarantee a Klein four-group, though?

Comment: @StackOverflow: It doesn't; but if you form the subgroups of double transpositions, then you will see that, for each $i$, each such group is the set of *all* double transpositions (and the identity) on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\setminus\{i\}$.

Comment: Thank you. I get that forming all possible double transpositions by excluding each $i$ in $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$ (with the identity) forms the Klein four-group. Is there any way to express this understanding using combinations (${n \choose k}$)?

Comment: You're welcome, @StackOverflow. Take your pick: ${n\choose 1}$ or ${n\choose n-1}$.

Comment: (Here $n$ is $5$.)